# Pass variable from web view to Xcode and store as NSString

Tags: php, ios, xcode, webview, nsstring

I am trying to pass a variable from a form filled out by a web view and store it as an NSString in Xcode. I have a signup page that stores the variable as a cookie. Then in another page I am trying to return that cookie as a variable and return it to Xcode. I think I am pretty close, but I need some assistance.

**Xcode:**

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/get_id.php"];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                       initWithTitle:@"Your ID" 
                       message:strResult 
                       delegate:self 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                       otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
return;
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$result = action($a, $b);
echo $result;

function action($a, $b){
    $your_email = $_COOKIE["your_email"];
    return $your_email;
}

?>
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance!

Comment: what is your problem? what is not working as you expect, exactly? is the php page accessed? do you get back some data? is the data wrong?

Comment: When using NSString and NSData, it doesn't want to load the cookie, i can get it to pass back any cookies/variables that were loaded within the page I am using, but it won't pull cookies that were stored by other web views. Maybe because NSData doesn't open a browser?

Comment: If I set the cookie directly within that page, it will work... But it won't load cookies from other pages... does that make any sense at all?